# Java stream API - avoid using same predicate twice to calculate average

Tags: java, java-stream

```
class A {
    double value;
    String key;
}

class B {
    List<A> aList;
}
```

Given `List<B> bList`, I want to calculate the average of the `value`s for a specific key `k`. Assume each `B` can hold only 0 or 1 times an instance of `A` with `key.equals(k)`.

I figured I could first filter `aList`, and later extract the value using `mapToDouble`:

```
double average = blist.stream().filter(
    b -> b.aList.stream().anyMatch(
        a -> a.key.equals(k)
    )
).mapToDouble(
    b -> b.aList.stream().filter(
        a -> a.key.equals(k)
    ).findFirst().get().value
).average().orElse(0);
```

But there is clearly a redundancy here, since I am filtering the same list by the same predicate twice (`a -> a.key.equals(k)`).

Is there a way to `mapToDouble` while omitting elements with missing matching `key`s at the same time?

**Edit:**

Here is a more concrete example, hopefully it will make it easier to understand:

```
String courseName;

...

double average = students.stream().filter(
    student -> student.getGrades().stream().anyMatch(
        grade -> grade.getCourseName().equals(courseName)
    )
).mapToDouble(
    student -> student.getGrades().stream().filter(
        grade -> grade.getCourseName().equals(courseName)
    ).findFirst().get().getValue()
).average().orElse(0);

System.out.println(courseName + " average: " + average);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
double average = bList.stream()
        .flatMap(b -> b.aList.stream())
        .filter(a -> a.key.equals(k))
        .mapToDouble(a -> a.value)
        .average()
        .orElse(Double.NaN);
```

If your objects have private field and getters, which they really should, it'd be like this:

```
double average = bList.stream()
        .map(B::getaList)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .filter(a -> a.getKey().equals(k))
        .mapToDouble(A::getValue)
        .average()
        .orElse(Double.NaN);
```

Comment: It returns 2.0 instead of 1.0 in case of `k="A"` and `bList=B(aList=[A(key="A", value=1.0), A(key="A", value=3.0)])`.   Is it right?

Comment: @saka1029 Why would you expect it to return `1.0`? The average of `1.0` and `3.0` is `2.0`.

Comment: @Andreas I think OP want to select one `A` instance at most in a `aList`.

Comment: @saka1029 OP said *"Assume each `B` can hold only 0 or 1 times an instance of `A` with `key.equals(k)`"*. With that **assumption**, the code in this answer is valid. Sure, the `findFirst()` logic in your answer may improve performance a bit, by short-circuiting the search, but that's different. The fact that you then provided invalid data in the comment just means that result is invalid/unexpected too. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @Andreas I understand.

Comment: @Andreas - can the same thing be done with `flatMapToDouble`? I guess it would make more sense, but I'm still struggling with the whole streams idea and could not put it all together...

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
double average = blist.stream()
    .map(b -> b.aList.stream()
        .filter(a -> a.key.equals(k))
        .findFirst())
    .filter(a -> a.isPresent())
    .mapToDouble(a -> a.get().value)
    .average().orElse(0);
```

Comment: This answer is better to a more general question.